# Why is toilet running every few minutes?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

Toilet is running every few minutes. I defaulted to flapper, changed it, same issue.

So then I was like eh float assemblies are like 15 bucks let me change that too, changed that, same issue.

Finally, took the extra 5 minutes and did the flapper seat and the seal between the tank and the bowl, no dice.

The thing still runs for a few seconds every few minutes.

Not sure what the pipe that fills the bowl is called but the float isn’t filling higher than that opening, so it’s not that either.

Any advice on what to look for next? If this helps at all: when I shut the water off, and leave it for a day or two, I don’t really see much of the water leaving the tank if any at all.

Comment: The float closes a valve/seal at the fill tube.  You changed/cleaned every other section, but the seal probably has a small leak/not sealing as new.

Comment: How high is the water in the toilet?  Compare the resting water level to the top of the overflow pipe.  Should be an inch or two below.  I am keenly interested in "exactly at the level of the overflow pipe".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the water level is not high enough to go down the overflow tube, it has to be  seeping past the flapper. To verify that put some strong brewed coffee in the tank and wait. If the water in the bowl becomes light brown or yellow, you know the water in the tank is leaking past the flapper.  Perhaps the seat needs cleaned and even the new part will not seal properly.

Comment: Good. Except don't waste good coffee on it. A couple of drops of food coloring will do.

Comment: Food coloring has been known to stain some older bowls. Don't ask me how I know.

Comment: This was it. It was such a slow leak, but that worked perfectly with the food coloring. It had to have been just a drop every few minutes. Thanks guys

Comment: Don’t see any staining. But I’ll flush it all through quickly and avoid it lol. Thanks again y’all.

Comment: Most food coloring responds well to bleach, especially undiluted.

Comment: On the other hand, coffee will wake up a sleepy toilet

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact: I *hate* it when that happens, it always falls asleep again before dinner.

Comment: Does it necessarily need to be the flapper?  Isn't it possible for the gasket between the flush valve flange and tank bottom to deteriorate and leak too? @MZawg did you also replace the valve, or just the flapper?